# Retrieving the mouse position

Tags: c#, winforms

i have the following code and am trying to retrieve the cursor/mouse position when it is over the drawn array and output it to the lab:

```
Label[ , ] _arr = new Label[4 , 4];

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{  
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {    
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
           {
              _arr[i ,j] = new Label();        
              _arr[i ,j].Text = ""+i+","+j;  
              _arr[i ,j].Size = new Size(50,50);        
              _arr[i ,j].Location = new Point(j*50,i*50);         //you can set other property here like Border or else         
              _arr[i, j].BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle ;   
              this.Controls.Add(_arr[i ,j]);
              **label2.Text = _arr[i, j].(System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition).ToString();**
           }  
    }
}
```

but i am having trouble with the line within double asterisks, can anyone help me resolve this error?

Comment: What's the problem? What is the output your getting and what's the output you're expecting?

Comment: I tried that but the values dont change, whereas if the mouse moves over any other part of the form then the values change,  it is as if the array blocks this

Comment: What error?  You haven't given one.

Comment: You'll have to remove the double asterisks. The code won't compile with them there; it will give you a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this.  It might not be the best way to do it, but it gives the desired result of updating the label as the mouse moves between each cell in your "array" on the form:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    _arr[i, j] = new Label();
                    _arr[i, j].Text = "" + i + "," + j;
                    _arr[i, j].Size = new Size(50, 50);
                    _arr[i, j].Location = new Point(j * 50, i * 50);         //you can set other property here like Border or else         
                    _arr[i, j].BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                    this.Controls.Add(_arr[i, j]);

                    _arr[i, j].MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseMove);
                }
            }
}

void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = ((Label)sender).Text;
}
```